# Google play services for AR isn't compatible with your device

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, augmented-reality, arcore

I bought a new phone Realme 7i (global version) , and it is in the list of
supported devices on ARcore
But every time Google play say :
"this application isn't compatible with your device"

[image]Please needs help
My build version is A18
[image: ARcore list device]

Answer (score 0):

Realme 7i is supported but Realme 7i (global version) is not, I think because of the Qualcomm Snapdragon difference.

[image: comparison]

Comment: No away that's impossible ! , How did you now that the chipset is the problem ??    I can't even trust Google arcore they didn't say nothing about that

Comment: Google did not say that they support Realme 7i (global version) but they support Realme 7i, which is a different phone. I think this is Realme fault.